# Composer Update - Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: php, composer-php

I am having a horrible problem figuring this out. I have a php project and am trying to use composer to update the project (code was give to me to update, i am not the original developer). I run the update and get this:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - suncat/mobile-detect-bundle dev-master requires mobiledetect/mobiledetectl
ib 2.7.* -> no matching package found.
    - suncat/mobile-detect-bundle dev-master requires mobiledetect/mobiledetectl
ib 2.7.* -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for suncat/mobile-detect-bundle dev-master -> satisfi
able by suncat/mobile-detect-bundle[dev-master].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your min
imum-stability setting
   see <https://groups.google.com/d/topic/composer-dev/_g3ASeIFlrc/discussion> f
or more details.

Read <http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common
 problems.
```

my Composer.json contains this:

```
{
    "name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
    },
    "require": {
        "aws/aws-sdk-php"                      : "2.4.*",
        "doctrine/orm"                         : ">=2.2.3,<2.4-dev",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle"             : "1.2.*",
        "doctrine/migrations"                  : "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle"  : "dev-master",
        "facebook/php-sdk"                     : "dev-master",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler" : "~2.0",
        "liip/imagine-bundle"                  : "dev-master",
        "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib"         : "dev-master",
        "php"                                  : ">=5.3.3",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle"           : "2.3.*",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle"        : "2.3.*",
        "sensio/generator-bundle"              : "2.3.*",
        "suncat/mobile-detect-bundle"          : "dev-master",
        "symfony/assetic-bundle"               : "2.3.*",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle"               : "2.3.*",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle"           : "2.3.*",
        "symfony/symfony"                      : "2.3.*",
        "twig/extensions"                      : "1.0.*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "bin"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml",
            "env-map": {
              "database_host": "DBHOST",
              "database_port": "DBPORT",
              "database_name": "DBNAME",
              "database_user": "DBUSER",
              "database_password": "DBPASS"
            }
        },
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same probleme ^^

Source : https://packagist.org/packages/suncat/mobile-detect-bundle

Change :

`"mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib"         : "dev-master",`

To :

`"mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib"         : "2.7.*",`

:)